# How do I create a page with a dynamic id?

Tags: form, php

Here’s an example: I have a job listing at www.example.com/designer and the user hits "apply" on that page. The user is then taken to a form. How can I know that the user came from www.example.com/designer and not www.example.com/developer?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, why wouldn't you just include that data as part of the form submission?

Comment: I think I didn’t explain clearly enough.

Basically what I need is that when a user submits the form, I know which job post they wanted to apply for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your redirect works, you can redirect and get the param in the template where the form is via:

```
{% set param_name = craft.request.param('param_name') %}
```

You can then set this param in your form template and post it to your action controller.

```
<input type='hidden' name='param_name' value='{{ param_name }}' />
```

In your action controller you can retrieve it by getting it from the post.

```
$param_name = craft()->request->getPost('param_name');
```

Is this anything you can use? Or need? Good luck!

Comment: Doesn’t solve my problem from the looks of it.

Here’s an example:
I have a job listing at www.example.com/designer and the user hits "apply" on that page. The user is then taken to a form. How can I know that the user came from www.example.com/designer and not www.example.com/developer?

Comment: Can you edit your question with this new information, i will update my answer then.

Comment: @ClintTabone you would just append the param to the "apply" link like so: `<a href="apply?param_name={{ craft.request.firstSegment }}">Apply</a>`